# vagrant : Failed to mount folders in Linux guest, "vboxsf" file system is not available?

Tags: php, github, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I have **VirtualBox 4.3.10** and **Vagrant 1.4.3** installed on my **Ubuntu 14.04** 64 bit Desktop.

Earlier, worked with **vagrant** technology but this time, multiple issue. Let me describe what I have done

1. clone private git to local system */opt/lampp/htdocs/{project}* : **done**
2. `root@desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/{project}$ vagrant up`

gives message on terminal while execution

> `GuestAdditions` versions on your host (4.3.10) and guest (4.2.0) do not match.

command completed with below message

> Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually beacuse the
>   "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that the guest
>   additions are properly installed in the guest and can work properly.
>   The command attempted was:

...

I understand this is version difference.

3. check `vagrant vbguest --status`

   > GuestAdditions 4.3.10 running --- OK.
4. Open browser and run with `http://192.168.0.33` (mentioned on README.md file of private git repo)  but it didn't work.

### UPDATE

5. Installed **vagrant-vbguest** as suggested [here](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/130#issuecomment-53687256)

   `$:sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

   > Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vbguest (0.10.0)'!

By doing this,message of version difference of `GuestAdditions` described in **2.** is gone

6. restart `vagrant halt` and then  `vagrant up`

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   [default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
>   [default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>   [default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>   [default] Forwarding ports...
>   [default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
>   [default] -- 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
>   [default] Booting VM...
>   [default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>   [default] Machine booted and ready!
>   GuestAdditions 4.3.10 running --- OK.
>   [default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
>   [default] Mounting shared folders...
>   [default] -- /vagrant
>
> Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually beacuse the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and can work properly. The command attempted was:

```
    mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` /vagrant /vagrant
    mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` /vagrant /vagrant
```

Do I need to change anything in local `vagrantfile` or change vagrant version or something else?

[Some say it is a bug](http://kvz.io/blog/2013/01/16/vagrant-tip-keep-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-sync/) whilesome gives solution for ubuntu < 14.04

Kindly suggest the solution hints and how to fix this issue?

Comment: found one more link : https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/130#issuecomment-53687256

Comment: can you do `lsmod` on guest and check if you have kernel modules installed?

`$ lsmod | grep vbox`

Comment: output is 
vboxpci                23194  0   
vboxnetadp             25670  0   
vboxnetflt             27613  0   
vboxdrv               339502  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci

Comment: It looks like `vboxsf` kernel module is not loaded from some reason. It's needed so you will be able to use shared folders. What about `modinfo vboxsf` ? Does it exists?

Comment: how do I check for the existence? Physical or terminal way?

Answer (score 13):

```
 vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

worked well for me (Virtual Box 5.0.22, Vagrant 1.8.4). It took muck longer to provision initially because the plugin downloaded gcc and a bunch of other tools before linking the guest additions .iso to the correct place.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently there is a bug in the VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.3.10 installer: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12879

There seems to be a simple workaround to this, by creating a symbolic link within Vagrant-VM:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions \
/usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

You could add this to your provisioning configuration to make sure you don't hit the bug again:

```
NEWEST_VBOXGUESTADDITIONS_DIR=`find /opt/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "VBoxGuestAdditions-*" | tail -n 1`;
if [[ ! -d "/usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions" && -n "$NEWEST_VBOXGUESTADDITIONS_DIR" ]];
then
    ln -s ${NEWEST_VBOXGUESTADDITIONS_DIR}/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but now moved from this topid :D. will check later.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code in "Vagrantfile" was the solution for me:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", type: "nfs"
```

Comment: This worked for me with Vagrant 1.9.4 and Virtual Box 5.1.20

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was fixed by rebuilding the kernel on the guest machine with
`sudo service vboxadd setup`.